# No audio with surf suckless.org web browser

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, browser, webkit

The `surf` web browser of [suckless.org](https://surf.suckless.org) is not playing any audio.
It was installed from the repositories on Xubuntu LTS 20.04.1. The default `pulseaudio` sound server works fine with other applications such as `vlc`.

When running `surf` from the command line, for example:

```
$ surf -m -a @ http://heppen.be:8091/m.html
```

I receive the following warnings:

```
(surf:25703): dbind-WARNING **: 15:44:29.674: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-NDwOQIOpuu: Permission denied

(WebKitWebProcess:25718): dbind-WARNING **: 15:44:29.833: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-NDwOQIOpuu: Permission denied
```

What is going wrong that `pulseaudio` is not receiving any audio from `surf`?

Another consideration is that `surf` depends on `libwebkit2gtk`. I am not sure if there is something similar to `chrome://settings/content/sound` as in [Blink engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) browsers?

Comment: My guess is that surf doesn't support websocket protocol. Try youtube, works for me.

Comment: @mkkot **What I forgot to mention:** Previously, this worked fine on Xubuntu LTS 18.04. However, `surf` was probably using Webkit v1 at the time. Youtube raises even more serious errors over here.